# Active Record can't create child , child is always nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-one

I have a model in rails called `campaign`, and another one called `export`

```
class Campaign < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :export
end

class Export < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :campaign
end
```

then I have code:

```
if campaign.export.nil?
    campaign.create_export(:tag => 'newtag')
end
```

This code create new line for export again and again because `campaign.export` is always `nil`.

Why I created export  by `campaign.create_export()`, but `campaign.export` is still `nil`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess here is that your validations for the export are preventing the creation of the export. If you call `create_<model>` and the validations fail, it will have a copy of the model that was not saved with the validations

Comment: thanks!   I have try to debug the "export". 
after just created, I can track the information, it is not be saved ,
because the model has a special line:
 has_one :export, :conditions => ["tag IS ?", nil]